# How can I convert TTF files to OTF format?

Tags: css, browser, font-face

I need to use  `@font-face` feature and my fonts are in TrueType (TTF) format, so how to convert TTF to OpenType (OTF) format.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you can use TTF file format directly in css :

```
@font-face { 
font-family: Vinegar; 
src: url(http://www.4bit.co.uk/testing/design01/vinegar.ttf); 
}

h3 {
font-family: Vinegar, "Times New Roman", Times, serif;
}
```

**It is working!**

[Or you can use this link to generate your font face!](http://www.fontsquirrel.com/fontface/generator)

Comment: Wouldn't this cause compatibility issues? *have heard something like that, but ain't sure...*

Comment: @Tom I have never seen a compatibility issue with this syntax. it is an old syntax and is supporting by browsers since 2000!

Comment: Well, here is an article http://randsco.com/index.php/2009/07/04/p680 ... scroll down to **C'mon, is it Really that Simple?** part, there you have it, IE only supporting `*.eot`. Or that's just a myth?

Comment: The site you link to doesn't seem to convert to OTF.

Comment: You need `ttf` and `eot` and `woff`! See my answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/20386012/1106393

Answer (score 14):

If you are on Linux, you can use FontForge, which can be scripted from Python.

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import fontforge
font = fontforge.open("STIXGeneral.otf")
font.generate("STIXGeneral.ttf")
```

Here is a longer python script that does this for a whole directory at a time:

http://fonts.fileformat.info/bin/otf2ttf.py

Comment: I guess you need `apt-get install fontforge python-fontforge` or if you are on OS X try http://stackoverflow.com/a/26313183/179581

Comment: You should disclose that the site is (presumably) yours.

Answer (score 11):

It was painfully hard to find how to do it correctly. Here is how I got it to work on OS X

```
$ brew install fontforge
$ fontforge  -c 'Open("my.ttf"); Generate("my.otf")'
```

I was desperately looking for `pip install fontforge` which does not exist and I haven't got it to work with python - I guess you need to compile it with `--enable-pyextension` or something.

Comment: Perfect answer for me, I'm on OS X as well and indeed, `pip install fontforge` didn't work. I already use Homebrew though, so your answer hit the nail on the head for me. :-)

Comment: This is the best answer. All the online converters are worthless as either don't work or require to pay.

Comment: if anyone else is having problems with this solution, make sure you try this:
`fontforge -c "f = fontforge.open(argv[1]); f.generate(argv[2])" ~/Downloads/logo.ttf ~/Downloads/logo1.otf`

Comment: Got it to work after adding imports `fontforge -c "import fontforge; from sys import argv; f = fontforge.open(argv[1]); f.generate(argv[2])" font.otf font.ttf`

Comment: Things have changed over the years. Feel free to submit it as a separate answer and edit this one to refer to it.

Answer (score 5):

A quick Google search for `ttf otf converter` gave me a number of results, such as:

https://onlinefontconverter.com

http://www.freefontconverter.com

http://www.font2web.com

No idea how well they work, but you can try them.

Answer (score 3):

For cross browser/mobile support you definitely need at least three formats:

1. Embedded OpenType: `eot` for Internet Explorer 6-8.
   There is a command line converter: http://code.google.com/p/ttf2eot/
2. Web Open Font Format: `woff` the W3C recommendation for webfonts: http://www.w3.org/TR/WOFF/
   A converter can be fond here: [http://people.mozilla.org/~jkew/woff/](http://people.mozilla.org/%7Ejkew/woff/)
3. and TrueType: `ttf` for Safari and Opera
4. (You could add Scalable Vector Graphics: `svg` for older iOS support…)

The bulletproof @font-face Syntax is this:

```
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Vinegar';
  src: url('vinegar.eot?') format('embedded-opentype'),
       url('vinegar.woff') format('woff'),
       url('vinegar.ttf') format('truetype'),
       url('vinegar.svg#svgVinegar') format('svg');
}
```

Further resources:
http://www.paulirish.com/2009/bulletproof-font-face-implementation-syntax/
http://www.fontspring.com/blog/the-new-bulletproof-font-face-syntax

You might also want to check out this tool:
https://github.com/zoltan-dulac/css3FontConverter

Comment: The latest version of IE is 11. Supporting IE 8 or lower is a waste of time unless specifically instructed by a major client. As such, the `url('vinegar.eot?') format('embedded-opentype')` line may be removed.

Answer (score 2):

As mentionned by others, fontforge scripting has switched to python.
I found the easiest way was to invoke python from the command line.

I could convert multiple ttf fonts to otf on Arch Linux this way, but it should work on other distros by installing fontforge with your favorite package manager.

```
[user@host]$ sudo pacman -S fontforge
[user@host]$ cd /path/to/your/fonts/folder
[user@host]$ python
>>> import fontforge
>>> import os
>>> fonts = [f for f in os.listdir('.') if f.endswith('.ttf')]
>>> for font in fonts:
...      f = fontforge.open(font)
...      f.generate(font[:-3] + 'otf')  # changes extension from ttf to otf
...
>>> exit()
```

Answer (score 1):

[With the Font Squirrel `@font-face` generator.](http://www.fontsquirrel.com/fontface/generator)

Answer (score 1):

You could also try this:

http://www.freefontconverter.com/