# Font converter: .ttf or .otf to .woff, .svg, etc

Tags: css, fonts, font-face

I've always used [Font Squirrel generator](http://www.fontsquirrel.com/fontface/generator) to make my @font-face kits, but recently I've run into trouble when trying to convert Helvetica Neue because it was blacklisted. Then I tried to use other generators, such as [Font2Web](http://www.font2web.com/). They do work, but some of the files they generate have very low quality; e.g., the font loses readability at 11px. I know it's the generator and a problem with some of the font formats because, depending on the file the browser loads, the font looks great.

So, what do? Is there a software that will do the job well? Or other online tools that generate the files in a higher quality?

P.S: Don't blame me for choosing Helvetica Neue, I'm just trying to implement it. If you know a nice, free font substitute to Helvetica Neue with lots of families like Extended and Black, it might also work if the designer likes it
.

Comment: I doubt anyone will 'blame you' for using Helvetica Neue....but it was blacklisted for a reason. You need a license to embed it on websites. Do you have a license? If not, then you can't use it.

Comment: It's available for licensing on http://www.fonts.com/web-fonts

Comment: @Adam I don't intend to buy a license. I want to illegaly embed the font because I'm a horrible, horrible criminal. And it's ok if you don't want to take part in such a disgusting crime, but just don't tell me I can't do it. Thanks.

Comment: Shure it's possible, but nobody will tell you how, cause it's illegal, and that will not be supported here. The best and _legal_ way is to choose alternatives to "Helvetica Neue", here[typekit](https://typekit.com/lists/alternatives-to-helvetica) for example.

Comment: Is there a way to find the EULA for a font? I have a few that I think may not be free for commercial use, and I would like to check them.

Comment: Know this is somewhat expired, but we had this problem too. We created a tool called [FontPrep](http://fontprep.com) to fix this problem.

Comment: What if you have a license? Then what?

Comment: Try http://fontforge.github.io. See how to use it on OS X http://stackoverflow.com/a/26313183/179581